# how ro calculate GAE billing?

Tags: google-app-engine

Assume that I upload 1GB (one gigabyte) data to my gae blobstore everyday. How can I calculate my storage cost at the end of first year?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the year you will have 365GB which will cost you 0.13$ ([in today prices](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing)) per GB per month, only for the blob storage you will pay 47.45$ per month (~1.5$ per day).

Comment: In my billing history, it charges $0.0043 per GB per day. Let's assume there is no free quota. First day it charges 0.0043, second 0.0043+0.0043*2, third day it will be 0.0043+0.0043*2+0.0043*3 and it goes like this. So for 365 days the total cost will be 0.0043 * 1 GB * 265 * 366 / 2 = $287.2185 (~ $0.7869 per day). Am I wrong?

Comment: Looks OK, I calculated only the last day.